# Python - Weird IF statement while using nested lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I don't understand why the `else` condition is not passed. Can somebody explain why?

```
#Python 3.4    
list=[]
list_of_list=[]

list.append("Test")
list.append("This")
list_of_list.append(list)
list=[]

print(list_of_list)
print(type(list_of_list))
print(len(list_of_list))

for element in list_of_list:
 if(element[0]=="Test"):
     print("[OK]")
 if(element[0]=="NO"):
     print("[OK]Condition is not verified")
 else:
     print("[OK]Why the condition is verified??")#<--------------------------
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['Test', 'This']]
<class 'list'>
1
[OK]
[OK]Why the condition is verified??
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
[['Test', 'This']]
<class 'list'>
1
[OK]
```

How can I fix the code?

Comment: Your second `if` should be an `elif`

Answer (score 3):

You have *two* `if` structures here:

```
if(element[0]=="Test"): # first block
    print("[OK]")
if(element[0]=="NO"): # second block
    print("[OK]Condition is not verified")
else: # attached to second block
    print("[OK]Why the condition is verified??")
```

`element[0]` is equal to `'Test'`, which it is, so it prints `"[OK]"`. It then checks whether it's equal to something else, which of course it isn't, so it then goes to the `else` block and prints `"[OK]Why the condition is verified??"`.

If you want to print only one thing, use `elif` to connect it all together:

```
if element[0]=="Test": # first block
    print("[OK]")
elif element[0]=="NO": # attached to first block
    print("[OK]Condition is not verified")
else: # still the same block
    print("[OK]Why the condition is verified??")
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.